# push changes to a branch without merging?

Tags: git, merge, push

Let's say I want to work on a branch, so a create one:

`git branch <name_branch>`

then I work on it `git checkout name_branch`

then I commit the changes:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "adding a change from the feature branch"
```

But I still have some work to be done on the branch, so I don't want to merge it yet, but I need to get it online, will `git push branch_name` do the trick? or should I merge with he master branch after each commit and then push the changes as recommended in the basic workflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not merge to *master* just to save my work-in-progress -- *master* should always be clean. With Git, branches (local and remote) are cheap. If you want to back-up your local branch to the remote, just do this (assuming your remote is named "origin" and you have <branch_name> checked out):

`git push -u origin <branch_name>`

Answer (score 4):

If it's truly a new branch like you said above, it will not merge into master.

The remote repository should create its own new branch with the changes where you can merge branches later.